# SSH - Putty Private Key and Passphrase

Tags: ssh, putty, passphrase

For giving remote access to a linux server, the administrator generated the public and private key pair probably using the Putty Key Generator and sent me the .ppk file. I loaded the .ppk file (having the private key) in Putty and can now access the server through Putty without being prompted for the passphrase or the password.

In order to access the remote server through the command line ssh program also, I copied the file below the .ssh directory in my $HOME. But when I try to access that server using the ssh command, the program asks me for the passphrase for the key (xyz.ppk) and does not accept a simple Enter and it terminates with the following message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)
```

What do I need to do to solve this issue ? I am just wondering if the private key is passphrase protected why doesn't Putty ask for the same.

I hope the keys generated by the Putty Key Generator work for the command line ssh also.

Answer (score 5):

Putty uses its own format for the key files, not a standard format. ssh can not use ppk files. I believe puttygen should be able to export your key to something more usable for ssh.

Comment: Detailed instructions are here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/473915